# Need help reading multiple values back from sql server database in asp code

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, database

here is my codebehind for grabbing data from database:

```
public static string getTestimonial()
{

    string username = "xxxxx";
    SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xxxxxxx"].ConnectionString);
    Conn.Open();
    string sql = "select testimonial,submitname from (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo.testimonials where username='" + username + "' ORDER BY newid()) as answer;";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, Conn);
    string test=cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    Conn.Close();

    return test;
}
```

yet when I try to display the data on my aspx page all I get is the first value:

```
<div class="span3">

                    <%= getTestimonial() %>

                </div>
```

can you please help me with a method of getting both the testimonial and the submitname from the query into variables?

Thanks!

Thanks! Solved! using:

```
public static string getTestimonial()
{

    string username = "xxxxxx";
    SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xxxxxxx"].ConnectionString);
    Conn.Open();
    string sql = "select testimonial,submitname from (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo.testimonials where username='" + username + "' ORDER BY newid()) as answer;";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, Conn);
    var test = new StringBuilder();

    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            test.Append(reader.GetString(0));
            test.Append(" and ");
            test.Append(reader.GetString(1));
        }
    }

    Conn.Close();
    return test.ToString();






}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteScalar()` will always return first column of the first row - a single value. You may want to rethink your approach, meanwhile the simplest way is to make your query return combined value:

```
string sql = "select testimonial + ' and ' + submitname from ....
```

Comment: I found out that yes executescalar only returns the first/first item...oops. and then found it was very easy using the above edited answer.

Comment: It might be an overkill DataReader, loops, StringBuilder to retrieve just 2 values.  But oh well, whatever works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, you probably should rewrite that function to not use inline SQL, as you are making your site vulnerable to SQL injection attacks potentially in writing it this way.  (presumably, userid is not set as a constant XXXXX in the actual function and is instead passed in somehow).

Comment: This is a good point, but should probably be a comment, not an answer